# Router push is not working in axios response - Vue/Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Example code by using `vue-property-decorator`:

```
@Component
export default class Login extends Vue {
  private mounted(): void {
    this.$router.push({ name: 'home' })
  }
}
```

Code above successfully redirects, when a component is mounted. But when using `this.$router.push()` in axios's response - nothing happens:

```
private login(): any {
  return this.$http
    .login(this.form)
    .then(resp => {
      this.$store.dispatch('authenticateUser', user)
      this.$router.push({ name: 'home' })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}
```

However in this case, `this.$store.dispatch()` works as inteded, but not `this.$router.push()`. What might be an issue?

Router config:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

// routes
import auth from '@/routes/auth'
import dashboard from '@/routes/dashboard'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    ...auth,
    ...dashboard
  ]
})
```

Auth middleware:

```
import store from '@/store'

export default {
  guest(to: any, from: any, next: any): void {
    if (store.state.auth.authenticated === false) {
      next()
    } else {
      next({
        path: '/dashboard'
      })
    }
  },
  auth(to: any, from: any, next: any): void {
    if (store.state.auth.authenticated) {
      next()
    } else {
      next({
        path: '/'
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Auth routes (@/routes/auth):

```
import Guard from '@/middlewares/auth'

export default [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'login',
    component: () => import('@/views/Login.vue'),
    beforeEnter: Guard.guest
  }
]
```

Issue is in auth middleware, if i remove `beforeEnter` router is pushing requested view.

Comment: Could you please share your router config? Also, it'll be helpful to see what error this.$router.push throws.

Comment: Push path of the view this.$router.push({path:''})

Comment: @Krantisinh, there's no errors, simply no redirect, updated my question with router.ts. Atul, doesn't matter, if it's path or name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use promise from `this.$store.dispatch()`, like this:

```
this.$store.dispatch('authenticateUser', user).then(() => {
  this.$router.push({ name: 'dashboard' })
})
```

Router push had no effect, because it was trying to navigate to another page, while action dispatch is not done yet, so my user wasn't authenticated, thus guard won't allowed me to redirect.